# Prove or disprove: deterministic Turing machine equivalence Nondeterministic Turing machine such that word

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Prove or disprove: deterministic Turing machine equivalence Nondeterministic Turing machine such that word accepts if and only if there are **exactly 2 accepted paths and all the others reject or no stop.**

I know that need at least 1 accepted path to accepting a word in a nondeterministic turning machine. At first glance, I think this is a disprove. Cannot build a deterministic Turing Machine with exactly 2 accepted paths and all the others rejects or no stop.

I have no idea how to disprove this claim  any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at *Micheal Sipser* **Introduction to the Theory of Computation** 3rd edition pages 178 and 179.

In short, the proof uses a three-tape turning machine $D$ (which is equivalent to an ordinary turning machine) to *simulate* a nondeterministic TM $N$ with a deterministic one. Then, $D$ will try all the possible branches of the original nondeterministic TM. If $D$ finds a branch with an accept state, $N$ will accept too.

For the specific, two paths of your problem, I suppose you can use the accept paths in series to each other. Suppose you have a turning machine $M$, which is determinstic and derived from $N$. Now for a given input on the tape you can run $M$ to reach *a* accept state. Suppose that you found the accept state in branch $q_i \rightarrow q_j$. Now you feed the output of $M$ to another turning machine $M_1$ which doesn't have the mentioned accept branch. If $M_1$ reaches an accept state *too*, then you will know that there are exactly (or at least) two branches that accept a given input.

Comment: I understood what u say but there is an ask in the question, the nondeterministic TM must have exactly 2 brancheses accept a state in your proof you show me that the deterministic TM is equivalent to the non-deterministic TM but what with the exactly 2 branch exactly?

Comment: @ATB I edited the answer.

Comment: now is better, Interesting what you saying, but to show equivalent I need to show 2 parts in the prove 1. that If I use the deterministic TM to accept like non-deterministic TM and 2. that if I use non-deterministic TM accept like deterministic TM and $L(M_{nondet})=L(M_{det})$ I understand what you try to say I need to think how I can do that but if u have any more improvement to this prove it will be appreciated, thanks!